# How to set to Android Facebook LoginButton to force authentication every time?

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

Using `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` is there any way to make the user reauthenticate if the permissions change?

Right now if I put different permissions every time on `mFacebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions();` and the user is already logged it dont grant the permissions and the user logs in.

Comment: Why are you asking for different read permissions at different times, and why are you putting them all on the Login button?

Comment: Is an update, I need new permissions now but the token is already there

Answer (score 1):

If the user is already logged in, then adding more permissions won't change the behavior on the login button (since it won't actually do anything if there's already an access token). If you want to incrementally ask for more permissions, of if you need additional ones because of an update, you should use the LoginManager directly.

What you can do is put the new set of required permissions on the LoginButton so that new users will accept them as they login, but for existing users, get the current set of permissions from the AccessToken, compare them against the permissions you need, and use LoginManager to ask for the new ones.

You should do this anyways because users can decline to give you certain permissions with the login dialog, and if you need those permissions later, you need to use the LoginManager.